# Getting CUDA error when trying to train MBART Model

Tags: python, nlp, computer-vision, machine-translation

```
from transformers import MBart50TokenizerFast
from transformers import MBartForConditionalGeneration
tokenizer = MBart50TokenizerFast.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-50-many-to-many-mmt",src_lang="", tgt_lang="")
model = MBartForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("facebook/mbart-large-50-many-to-many-mmt");
batch_size = 8

args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
output_dir="./resultsMBart",
evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
learning_rate=3e-5,
per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size,
per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size,
save_total_limit=3,
num_train_epochs=3,
predict_with_generate=True,
fp16=False,
report_to = "none")

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
model,
args,
train_dataset=tokenized_datasets["train"],
eval_dataset=tokenized_datasets["validation"],
data_collator=data_collator,
tokenizer=tokenizer,
compute_metrics=compute_metrics)
trainer.train()
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 978.00 MiB (GPU 0; 15.74 GiB total capacity; 13.76 GiB already allocated; 351.00 MiB free; 14.02 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch) 
If reserved memory is >> allocated memory try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid    fragmentation.  
See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I have recently started working in NLP and was trying to train MBART Model using my data set but every time I set it for training,I get a CUDA error.I have tried decreasing batch size as well as killing all processes on the GPU to prevent this error but I cannot seem to figure out a solution.Would anyone have an idea on how I could fix this and train the model?
The data set I am using has approximately 2 million sentences but that didn't lead to a problem when I tried using other models,so I have no idea why this is occuring,any help would be well appreciated.
The GPU I am using is NVIDIA Quadro RTX 5000.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that you can try in order to reduce the memory footprint and avoid OOM issues:

- **Gradient accumulation**: When using gradient accumulation, gradient calculation is done in smaller steps rather than all at once for a batch. In order to use this, all you have to do is set the `gradient_accumulation_steps` argument to a number that would fit into memory, and modify the `per_device_train_batch_size` to `original_batch_size/gradient_accumulation_steps`. For example, assuming your GPU can take up to a batch size of 2 (and ideally you want to max it out), and you intend to train with a batch size of 8, this is how you should set up your training arguments to ensure that it fits into memory:

> ```
> batch_size = 8
> gradient_accumulation_step = 2 #needs to be a batch size that can fit into memory 
>
> args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
> output_dir="./resultsMBart",
> evaluation_strategy = "epoch",
> learning_rate=3e-5,
> gradient_accumulation_steps = gradient_accumulation_steps, 
> per_device_train_batch_size=batch_size/gradient_accumulation_step,
> per_device_eval_batch_size=batch_size/gradient_accumulation_step,
> save_total_limit=3,
> num_train_epochs=3,
> predict_with_generate=True,
> fp16=False,
> report_to = "none")
> ```

- **Gradient checkpointing**: This approach helps save memory by reducing the memory overhead by saving only selective activations as opposed to saving all of them. To use this, the `gradient_checkpointing` needs to be set to `True`

I highly recommend reading the [Performance and scalability section of the transformers documentation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.2/en/performance) to understand the pros and cons of the aforementioned approaches better, and to familiarize yourself with other techniques as well such as mixed precision training and optimizer usage.